# Aptana Installation error message

Tags: installation, aptana3

A very basic question. Struggling to install Aptana. I've installed Git & Eclipse and updated Java but the installation error message reads:

> Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Try installing [NodeJS from Aptana](http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows) first.</strike>

Install NodeJS, download the installer at [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Then install Aptana.